# Create or Update in Laravel 5.6 giving "fillable" exception message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have the following code:-

```
$token = encrypt($guuid);
$tokenDetail = AdminConfig::select('config_value')
                ->where(array(
                        'config_key'    => 'expiry_duration',
                        'is_delete'     => 0
                ))->first();
$expiryDuration = $tokenDetail['config_value']; 
$expiryTime = date("dmyHis", time() + $expiryDuration);
$created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$tokenUpdated = AppToken::updateOrCreate(array(
                             'user_id' => $user_id, 
                             'token' => $token),
                               array('expiry'=>$expiryTime,
                               'created_date'=>$created_at,
                               'modified_date'=>$created_at)
                    );
if($tokenUpdated)
{
    $return['status'] = 1;
    $return['token'] = $token;
}
else
{
    $return['status'] = 0;
    $return['token'] = $token;
}
return $return;
```

I am using the `updateOrCreate` method so that if a record exists, then it will be updated. Else it will be created.

I am getting an exception message,

```
Add [user_id] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Http\Model\AppToken].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use the `updateOrCreate` method as you did, you have to add `user_id` to the `fillable` property within the `AppToken` class as demonstrated below.

```
class AppToken extends Model
{
    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'token'
    ];
}
```

More information on this topic is available [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by adding this code in your Model file :-

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Like this

```
class AppToken extends Model
{
     protected $guarded = [];
     public function fun_name()
     {
          //function code 
     }
}
```

Hope this will help :)